# How to define the type of a MarkupExtension provided value?

Tags: c#, xaml, types, markup-extensions

I have an issue in xaml where a custom `MarkupExtension`'s `ProvideValue` returns a string, but the xaml "compilation" doesn't know that and gives the following error: `A key for a dictionary cannot be of type 'MyNamespace.MyExtension'. Only String, TypeExtension, and StaticExtension are supported.` That error is unfortunate, since I know that the value provided will, in fact, be a string, which is an accepted type, as per the error message. Here is an example that reproduces the error:

Extension code:

```
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(String))]
public class MyExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<sys:Double x:Key="{my:MyExtension}">99</sys:Double>
```

EDIT2: Simplified the question as I found after testing that it could be more specific

Comment: Have you tried putting `[MarkupExtensionReturnType]` on your class?

Comment: I didn't know this attribute existed! Sounds just like what I needed.. However, unfortunately, using it doesn't seem to have any effect.. Updating post to reflect this change

Comment: It seems like you can bypass the error by inheriting from `TypeExtension` instead of `MarkupExtension` (which is kinda dirty since there's nothing related to `TypeExtension` with your markup extension) and override `ProvideValue` again but I didn't manage to try using the resource for real. It'd be good if you could provide a sample use case for `MyDictionaryExtension` (using a resource inside it to set a TextBox's Text for example)

Comment: Adding a usage example for the dictionary, will check if TypeExtension helps later/tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your problem, you can make `MyExtension` inherit from either `StaticExtension` or `TypeExtension` (both from `System.Windows.Markup`). This doesn't look really clean since `MyExtension` isn't related to `TypeExtension` or `StaticExtension` but that's the only way I know of to bypass the compile time check that makes sure resource keys are only of type `String`, `TypeExtension` or `StaticExtension`.

After inheriting from `TypeExtension` or `StaticExtension` there's nothing more to do than if you were inheriting directly from `MarkupExtension` (so you only have to override `ProvideValue`) with your current implementation.

Comment: While making the extension inherit from TypeExtension doesn't seem like a very clean (as the extension is *not*, in fact, a TypeExtension), it does work..
I will be updating the question as I have managed to simplify the use case.